# jQuery UI Autocomplete throws Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'autocomplete'

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to introduce the jQuery UI autocomplete feature to a widget in a Rails 3.1.3 app. It doesn't do anything and on inspecting the scripts in Chrome developer tools, I see the following:

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $("#location").autocomplete({
    locations.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'autocomplete'
    source: ["foo", "food", "four"]
  });
});
```

I've included jQuery UI in application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

My coffeescript has the following:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#location').autocomplete
    source: ["foo", "food", "four"]
```

What am I missing!?

Comment: Is the jQuery and jQuery UI loaded to the document ?
Check the network tab in developer tools.

Do you call $('#location').autocomplete() after document ready ?

Comment: @soderslatt Yes. I see jquery.js then jquery-ui.js and then some others before locations.js. "jQuery ->" does the document ready for me.

Comment: do you include any other JavaScript libraries like Prototype ? it may be a jquery conflict issue. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: @soderslatt thanks for the comment. It led me to investiagate and it turns out that since I also had active_admin, "//=require_tree ." was adding an older version of jQuery from the active_admin/vendor path which was removing the autocomplete method. Got rid of the "//=require_tree ." for now and explicitly added "//=require locations" and it works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that since I also had active_admin, "//=require_tree ." was adding an older version of jQuery from the active_admin/vendor path which was removing the autocomplete method. Got rid of the "//=require_tree ." for now and explicitly added "//=require locations" and it works just fine.

Comment: Just to add, the same thing was essentially happening to me, but because I was using WYMeditor and it also came with an old version of JQuery.

Comment: Can you please explain this step by step ? I am having the same error but I am using bootstrap.